# Tell me what the compiler does here?

Tags: c, linux

Please tell me what it does?

```
$ ar -r libsldap.a
```

Comment: What makes you think the *compiler* is doing something here? Have you seen this as a result of calling `make`?

Comment: It's probably faster on a Unix-alike system to type `man <command>` for a quick check than it is to post to StackOverflow.  And a whole lot less embarrassing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ar -r libsldap.a list-of-object-files

This line creates Linux static library, which is actually archive file that contains one or more .o files. Compiler is used previously to create these .o files.

http://www.linux.org/docs/ldp/howto/Program-Library-HOWTO/static-libraries.html

Comment: +1 for being the first to explain what is `ar` ( *ar* -chive) and so inform others without having to *click* to know simple things.

Answer (score 14):

"Teach a man to fish", I say:

[`> man ar`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/1/AR/)

```
[...]
DESCRIPTION
       The GNU ar program creates, modifies, and extracts from archives.  An
       archive is a single file holding a collection of other files in a
       structure that makes it possible to retrieve the original individual
       files (called members of the archive).
[...]
```

`man` is your friend.

Comment: @Yossarian: You're entitled to your opinion, of course. Neither of @pravin's questions have suggested the discovery or usage of `man`. @pravin is welcome to correct me and say "I've consulted the manpage but I'm still no clear as to what `ar` does...". Until then, my answer stands.

Comment: @Yossarian? Have you read ESR's thoughts on RTFM? http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#rtfm